# ¿Por qué las CSP con *. no funcionan si hay / en la URL?

Tags: .htaccess, seguridad, cors

Tengo unas URL externas que cargan imágenes, estilos etc en mi web.

Este es un trozo de lo que tengo en `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.midominio.com"
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none';
    script-src 
      'self' 
      'unsafe-inline' 
      https://www.googletagmanager.com 
      https://use.fontawesome.com 
      https://cdn.polyfill.io 
      https://code.jquery.com 
      *.google-analytics.com 
      *.analytics.google.com 
      *.cse.google.com 
      *.google.com; 
      # ... etc 
</IfModule>
```

Hay un script que se carga desde esta URL: `www.google.com/cse/......` y ese script tiene elementos variables. Para no dar acceso a todo google (como hago en la última directiva) he intentando quitar: `*.google.com` y poner `*.google.com/cse`, pero en ese caso no funciona, me deniega la carga del script.

¿Existe alguna forma de dar permiso a una URL que incluya `/carpeta`? ¿Por qué en ese caso no funciona `*.`?

He intentado así y tampoco funciona: `*.google.com/cse/.*` y también `*.google.com/cse/*.*`

Comment: ¿La directiva `script-src` es de algún módulo de Apache? No me suena, ¿podrías enlazar a su documentación? Me suena más a la cabecera HTTP [`default-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src), ¿me equivoco?

Comment: Creo que es debido a que una mezcla entre comodines en el nombre del equipo y en la URL no es válido: https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#framework-directive-source-list . Redactando respuesta.

Comment: @OscarGarcia sí, lo tengo en el `.htaccess`, dentro de `<IfModule mod_headers.c></IfModule>`.

Comment: Yo diría que es porque se produce una redirección de`https://google.com/cse` a `https://cse.google.com` y la URL final queda así `https://cse.google.com/cse`...

Comment: O incluso si no es esa la redirección, posiblemente haya una redirección. Toca seguirle la pista a los requests pa cargar ese recurso....

Comment: @FranciscoJavier ¿en ese caso debería pasar no, pues tengo puesto esto: `*.cse.google.com`? Y es que de hecho, algunos recursos se cargan con `www.cse.google.com` y otros con `google.com/cse`, cosa que me pareció extraña.

Comment: @A.Cedano Y seguramente está pasando, pero como se redirige por `Google` a una url de búsquedas personalizadas: `https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=....` y esta no encuentra el identificador `cx`, pues te banea...

Comment: @FranciscoJavier pues lo he solucionado, mi error era no poner la barra después de `cse`, o sea, probé así: `*.google.com/cse`, y así: `*.google.com/cse.*` y así: `*.google.com/cse/.*` y así: `*.google.com/cse/*.*`, pues había que ponerlo así: **`*.google.com/cse/`** o sea, barra después de `cse`.

Comment: @A.Cedano La teoría de la navaja de Ockham se demuestra de nuevo... ;-D De todos modos, me alegro de que lo hayas podido resolver. Un saludo.